# Copy info into a blank column between specified range, or insert new column if blank is not available

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to insert Range A2:A7 from sheets("templates") between myFirstColumnT and myLastColumnT with the conditions of; If all Rows in the named range "Week2" between myFirstColumnt and myLastColumnT are empty then paste A2:A7 from Sheets("Templates") Else insert newcolumn and paste A2:A7 from Sheets("Templates")

This is what I have tried, but it will not run multiple times when i is > 1, help is much appreciated.

```
For i = 1 To myWorksheet.Cells(36, myWorksheet.Range("TuesdayStarts").Column)
        myFirstColumnT = myWorksheet.Cells.Find( _
                                             What:="TS", _
                                             LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                             LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                             SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
                                    

        myLastColumnT = myWorksheet.Cells.Find( _
                                             What:="TE", _
                                             LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                             LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                             SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
                                         
        For newcol = myLastColumnT To (myFirstColumnT + 1) Step -1
            If myWorksheet.Cells(myWorksheet.Range("Week2").Row, newcol).Value = "" Then
                Sheets("Templates").Range("A2:A7").Copy
                myWorksheet.Cells(41, newcol).PasteSpecial
            Else
                myWorksheet.Columns(newcol).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
                Sheets("Templates").Range("A2:A7").Copy
                myWorksheet.Cells(41, newcol).PasteSpecial
            End If
         Next newcol
    Next i
```

Comment: Side note: why `Step -100000000`?

Comment: Use `WorksheetFunction.CountA` to see if any cells in the range are populated perhaps.

Comment: step-1000000000 I don't know, I am new to VBA, but when I had it set as step -1, the loop would double itself with each iteration of running the code,.  I found when I set the steps to -2 it allowed me to run the code twice before doubling the amount of inserting columns